# Import / pull-in external .js file if not already loaded through another .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, html5-canvas

I am trying to modify a automatically generated .js file to query if a certain external file is loaded and if it isn't, then load the file.

More specifically, I am working with a series of documents generated by Tumult Hype. The application generates a series of .js files. However, there is a functionality that is not included which would allow fully responsive scaling of the resulting embedded code.

Tumult Hype has a solution for that as defined in their support knowledge-base at http://hype.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/259191-responsive-size-for-your-project-resizing-your-document-to-fit-in-a-window-or-element which recommends loading jQuery and adding the following script to the head of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var alsoenlarge = true;
$(function(){
  if(isScalePossible()){
    $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'}); //no scroll bars
    $('#scalecontainer').css({position: 'absolute', margin: 0}); //centering by hand after resize

// Run scale function on start
    scaleSite();
    scaleSite();  

    // run scale function on browser resize
    $(window).resize(scaleSite);
  }
});
function scaleSite()
{
  windoww = $(window).width();
  windowh = $(window).height();
  sitew = $('#scalecontainer').width();
  siteh = $('#scalecontainer').height();
  f = windoww/sitew;
  f = windowh/siteh<f?windowh/siteh:f;
  if(!alsoenlarge && f>1) f = 1;
  $('#scalecontainer').css({
    "-moz-transform"    : "scale("+f+")",
    "-webkit-transform" : "scale("+f+")",
    "-ms-transform"     : "scale("+f+")",
    "-o-transform"      : "scale("+f+")",
    "transform"         : "scale("+f+")",
    "left"              : ((windoww-(sitew*f))/2)+"px",
    "top"               : ((windowh-(siteh*f))/2)+"px"
  });
}
function isScalePossible()
{
  can = 'MozTransform' in document.body.style;
  if(!can) can = 'webkitTransform' in document.body.style;
  if(!can) can = 'msTransform' in document.body.style;
  if(!can) can = 'OTransform' in document.body.style;
  if(!can) can = 'transform' in document.body.style;
  if(!can) can = 'Transform' in document.body.style;
  return can;
}
</script>
```

However, as this code will be used in a Joomla environment and will not be required site-wide, but only on specific pages, I would prefer not to call the script unless expressly needed.

The Hype-generated code has several parts.

There is html such as this:

```
<!-- copy these lines to your document: -->
<div id="scaletest_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1024px;height:800px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scaletest_Resources/scaletest_hype_generated_script.js?29990"></script>
</div>
<!-- end copy -->
```

This html imports a specific .js file called `scaletest_hype_generated_script.js` (the scaletest portion of the name changes from hype document to hype document)

This document then loads all the resources needed for the hype file to be rendered by the web browser.

On lines 25-40 of the `scaletest_hype_generated_script.js` file is a query to verify if another .js file called `HYPE.js` is loaded, and if it is not, to load that file. The code is as follows:

```
// load HYPE.js if it hasn't been loaded yet
if(typeof HYPE_108 == "undefined") {
    if(typeof window.HYPE_108_DocumentsToLoad == "undefined") {
        window.HYPE_108_DocumentsToLoad = new Array();
        window.HYPE_108_DocumentsToLoad.push(HYPE_DocumentLoader);

        var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.type= 'text/javascript';
        scriptElement.src = resourcesFolderName + '/' + 'HYPE.js?hype_version=108';
        headElement.appendChild(scriptElement);
    } else {
        window.HYPE_108_DocumentsToLoad.push(HYPE_DocumentLoader);
    }
    return;
}
```

What I would like to do is add 2 additional queries to this file, immediately after the above code:

1. Test to see if jQuery is loaded, and if not, to load jQuery
2. Test to see if the script mentioned at the beginning of this post is loaded, and if not, to load the script.

I would then save the above script as an external .js file and place it relative to the root of the site in a directory called `/hype`. The file would be called `scaleableHype.js`

Also, I would like to modify the path to the `HYPE.js` file. As there are dozens of hype animations on the site, it is redundant to call multiple copies of the same file. By default, the `HYPE.js` file is in the resource folder of each hype content.

The current structure of my directories is as follows:

```
/hype
  |-/resourceFolder1
  |--|--HYPE.js
  |--|--PIE.htc
  |--|--image1.jpg
  |--|--documentName1_hype_generated_script.js
  |-/resourceFolder2
  |--|--HYOE.js
  |--|--PIE.htc
  |--|--pic1.png
  |--|--documentName2_hype_generated_script.js
```

I would like the scripts, for example `documentName1_hype_generated_script.js` and `documentName2_hype_generated_script.js` to load the same (not multiple) copies of the `HYPE.js` file, thus eliminating the duplication.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to use $doc = &JFactory::getDocument(); $doc->addScript("src of js"); this function will load the js only once if you loaded it will not load again.

Comment: Well, the problem is that each documentName_hype_generated_script.js refers to a different copy of the HYPE.js file that is in the same directory as the documentName_hype_generated_script.js file. I need to first modify the files to all look for the same HYPE.js file. The other part of my question is extending the call to also load another .js file that currently isn't there. That .js file will just have the script at the tp of this post in it.

Comment: Have you looked at [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/)?

Comment: @robertc yepnope.js seems like a good solution, but the question I have still is how do I modify the code of each of the multiple `documentName_hype_generated_script.js` to share the same HYPE.js and PIE.htc thus removing over a dozen redundant duplicate files AND just as importantly adding the new `scaleableHype.js` to the array with a test to see if jQuery is already loaded. I'm pretty green on writing/editing javascript and without a bit of hand-holding, will fall flat on my face.

Comment: I have uploaded the complete source files for one set of resources to pastebin. If you access my pastebin at http://pastebin.com/u/alisamii you will see 5 files. Inside the file **copain.html**, the code on lines 21-27 is copied into the Joomla article. That code references and loads **copain_hype_generated_script.js** which on lines 25-40 verifies that the **HYPE.js** file is loaded or not, and loads it if not. I cannot determine where **PIE.htc** gets loaded. I want to modify the path to **HYPE.js** so it is in the parent directory and add a test for jQuery and the new **hypeScale.js** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this code to detect **documentName1_hype_generated_script.js** and **documentName2_hype_generated_script.js** are already being loaded and if not, load it.

```
<?php
   if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('HYPE')){
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('HYPE',true);
        $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/to/HYPE.js");
    }

    if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
        $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/to/jquery.js");
    }

    if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('hypeScale')){
        JFactory::getApplication()->set('hypeScale',true);
        $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "path/to/hypeScale.js");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Lodder. It's the other way around. The HTML loads `documentName1_hype_generated_script.js`. That in turn loads `HYPE.js` which is in the same directory as `documentName1_hype_generated_script.js`. Each `documentName1_hype_generated_script.js` is in its own directory, with its own copy of `HYPE.js` and `PIE.htc` So I have dozens of directories called `documentName*_Resources`, each with duplicate `HYPE.js` and `PIE.htc` plus all images and a file called `documentName*_hype_generated_script.js`. I want 1 `HYPE.js`, 1 `PIE.htc`, then verify jQuery is loaded and then load `hypeScale.js`.

Comment: @alisamii - I have updated my answer to detect if **HYPE.js**, **jQuery.js**, and **hypeScale.js** are being loaded and if not, load them. I'm not too sure on the PIE one though as it's a **.htc** file.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Now that is in PHP, so I would need to put it in a php file. If I want these if else statements to be executed from another .js file, how would that be done? The flow is: Joomla page loads --> code in page `<!-- copy these lines to your document: -->
<div id="scaletest_hype_container" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1024px;height:800px;">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scaletest_Resources/scaletest_hype_generated_script.js?29990"></script>
</div>
<!-- end copy -->` loads .js file --> and the .js file executes these tests?

Comment: you can't out this in a PHP file, so what I recommend you do is, add it to the index.php file in your template folder ;)

Comment: Well, that would mean that it would load these on every page, and I don't need these scripts loaded except on the specific pages where they are needed. So, although your solution is good if the scripts were needed globally on the site, it doesn't address my specific needs.

Comment: In which case you can download [DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470) which is a plugin that allows you to add custom PHP code in articles or you can insert it into a component if you're using one, but be sure to do a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: Well, DirectPHP is not Joomla 3.x compatible, and it also conflicts with Gantry, the Framework I am using, even on Joomla 2.5x

Comment: ah you're using Joomla 3. You should have said ;) In which case you can use [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) which allows you to add more than just PHP code to articles.

Comment: Well, not working. If I put the php code above with correct paths at the top of the article in the {source}{/source} tag, my site loads blank. If I take it out, it loads.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to ensure that jQuery is always loaded before running your script. If so, include this before your script block everywhere you're worried jQuery may not be available:

```
<!-- note that we are specifying a version here, that may or may not meet your need -->
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!-- If you want to provide a version on your own server, you could do this instead -->
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

HOWEVER, if instead you just want to prevent your script running if jQuery isn't loaded yet

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
if (window.jQuery) {
    var alsoenlarge = true;
    $(function(){
      if(isScalePossible()){
        $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'}); //no scroll bars
        $('#scalecontainer').css({position: 'absolute', margin: 0}); //centering by hand after resize

    // Run scale function on start
        scaleSite();
        scaleSite();  

        // run scale function on browser resize
        $(window).resize(scaleSite);
      }
    });
    function scaleSite()
    {
      windoww = $(window).width();
      windowh = $(window).height();
      sitew = $('#scalecontainer').width();
      siteh = $('#scalecontainer').height();
      f = windoww/sitew;
      f = windowh/siteh<f?windowh/siteh:f;
      if(!alsoenlarge && f>1) f = 1;
      $('#scalecontainer').css({
        "-moz-transform"    : "scale("+f+")",
        "-webkit-transform" : "scale("+f+")",
        "-ms-transform"     : "scale("+f+")",
        "-o-transform"      : "scale("+f+")",
        "transform"         : "scale("+f+")",
        "left"              : ((windoww-(sitew*f))/2)+"px",
        "top"               : ((windowh-(siteh*f))/2)+"px"
      });
    }
    function isScalePossible()
    {
      can = 'MozTransform' in document.body.style;
      if(!can) can = 'webkitTransform' in document.body.style;
      if(!can) can = 'msTransform' in document.body.style;
      if(!can) can = 'OTransform' in document.body.style;
      if(!can) can = 'transform' in document.body.style;
      if(!can) can = 'Transform' in document.body.style;
      return can;
    }

}
</script>
```